# How I can use infinite scrolling in the webpage where I want it?

Tags: jquery, html, interaction, infinite-scroll

I am using an infinite scrolling jQuery plugin to implement a Twitter-like paging feature. Now, when I click on the **more** link, the request goes to server and it gives the response as HTML. First I tries using jQuery templates, and later I changed everything because I found nothing online to do that using JSON.

Well, now I have a problem that only the code does not append the response to the existing content on the page. It just sends the request and never appends to document's existing mockup.

Demo of plugin: `http://www.infinite-scroll.com/trigger.html`

I want to have code like this

```
<div id="result">
    <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need it that when user clicks on the **more** link, then more 'li's come from response and append to the 'li' inside of the result 'ul'.

```
 $('#result ul').infinitescroll({
        navSelector: "a#next:last",
        // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector: "a#next:last",
        // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector: "#result ul"
        // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    });

    // kill scroll binding
    $(window).unbind('.infscr');

    // hook up the manual click guy.
    $('a#next').click(function () {
        $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
        return false;
    });

    // remove the paginator when we're done.
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opt) {
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a plugin to accomplish this. This is done with some simple lines of jQuery:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6fnTT/9/

```
$("a").live("click", function(){
    var data = "<li style='display:none'>Text3</li>";

    $("ul").append(data);
    $("li:hidden").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**data** might be anything (just be sure it is invisible to have the fade effect and you need to edit the li:hidden). E.g. it could be the result of an ajax request. Depending on the type of result (e.g. html or json) you would need to prepare it to make it fit into your html.

If you have trouble with your ajax response please post the code.

Comment: you are right. now i feel why i spent a lot's of time in this whenever i can write my own script. thanks a lot